# how to use return in asyncio python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio


def test_async_call(test):
    return test

def test_another_async_call(xyz):
    return xyz

async def first_one():
    return test_async_call('hello')
async def second_one():
    return test_another_async_call('hi')

async def final_one():
    tasks = first_one(), second_one()
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

I am pretty new to asyncio and trying to call multiple functions in async, is the above way not correct? How can i call multiple functions in async way.

Comment: What is your actual use case? What are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (this is just a concept; this will not work how you want in your program)

```
async def main():
    return "hi"
```

Then, start the async program by doing this:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Now, `result` will be equal to `"hi"`. The way I'd recommend starting further async functions is to simply do:

```
variablename = await asyncfunction(param)
```

Hope this helps.